# how to link to anchor tag in different section

Tags: html, anchor, parallax, sections

this is my code in two ways in (li)s and yet neither are working:

```
<ul class="submenuItems">
          <li><a href="index.html#ourpurpose">Our Purpose</a></li>
          <li><a href="#scope">Scope</a></li>
```

and for the target this is the code :

```
<h1 id="ourpurpose">Our Purpose<h1>
...
<h1 id="scope">Scope</h1>
```

i want to link it knowing that both  are in the same `<section>` in a parallax page but separated by images and divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `#scope` and `#ourpurpose` is right, in this case you need to add `section` (You can also can use `div`)

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}

.topics {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="submenuItems">
  <li><a href="#ourpurpose">Our Purpose</a></li>
  <li><a href="#scope">Scope</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="ourpurpose-section">
<h2>ourpurpose</h2>
<div class="topics" id="ourpurpose"> I am topics</div>
<p>Some Text</p>
<div class="images"><!-- Some images --></div>
</section>
<section id="scope-section">
<h2>scope</h2>
<div class="topics" id="scope">topics</div>
<p>Some Text</p>
<div class="images"><!-- Some images --></div>
</section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: the problem is both `<h1>` are in the same section separated by images and divs.

Comment: **DO NOT** use `h1` tags twice.. you must change your code kinda.

Comment: i know, the issue is both are separated topics and paragraphs.

Comment: `both are separated topics and paragraphs` so what's the problem? please explain more.

Comment: i have 3 sections..each contain topics (titles, paragraphs & some images)
in my menu I have a list of these topics by their titles, my problem is i want when i click on a specific title in the list it takes me to that specific topic regarding which section that topic is.

Comment: So my answer very close to your goal, isn't it? just set the `id` to your `topics` instead of each `section` @JTAmin

Comment: believe me i tried naming and ID'ing `<div>`, `<h1>` even `<p>` and yet nothing...
is there a way to specify an ID in a specific section so i can use it in `href=""` ? just thinking..

Comment: @JTAmin see updated answer, it's already go to topic section (blue section) , is it still not what you looking for?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use ID "ourpurpose" in the href field of link. If the contents are on the same page.

```
<a href="#ourpurpose">Our Purpose</a>
```

Comment: I gave to `<li>`s as samples and neither are working.
your code is matching the second `<li>`  `<li><a href="#scope">Scope</a></li>` and also not working